# How to use Regexp in mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a mysql table like following

```
jobno | duration
----------------
1     |  1 hr
2     |  3 hrs
3     |  1 hr 30 mins
4     |  2 hrs 15 mins
5     |  1 hr 15 min
6     |  45 mins
7     |  30 min
```

Is it possible to select the jobs with duration less than 2 hrs ?
After spending a lot of time in google i found that there is regexp function in mysql. But is that applicable in this case?
Am new to mysql. Pls help me guys.

Comment: I would question your format. Life would be simpler if you just stored all durations in minutes. You could easily convert them to the text versions in PHP

Comment: yes @rjdown now i regret. :( But it is not possible,  because my table already contains 300000 rows and it is really hard to change all those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from TableName where duration NOT REGEXP '^([^1]|[1-9][0-9]+) hr.*'
```

Try this.This will work.[**See here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba4de/2/0)

For less than `3` you can use

```
select * from TableName where duration  REGEXP '^([1-2] hr|[0-9]+ min).*'
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba4de/12/0

Similarly for `4` use `[1-3]` and so on.

Comment: Good one @vks But how cani make it flexible with all durations? for example <3 hrs or <4hrs etc.

Comment: yeah this is what i was searching for. Working well. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: select * from TableName
where duration NOT REGEXP '^([^1-2]|[1-9][0-9]+) hr.*'

The one which works for me. Thanks for guiding me into this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your `duration` column format. why cant you just use `like`:

```
select * from yourTableName where duration like '1 hr%' or duration NOT like '%hr%';
```

or if you are looking for flexibility like below `4 hours` try this:

```
select * from yourTableName
where duration REGEXP '^[1-3].*$' or duration not like "%hr%";
```

Comment: That could work for this set on the entries whose duration is less than *one* hour, but can you think of a way to find the ones whose duration is less than *two* hours?

Comment: Oh that is good thought. @noob But How can if i want to choose <4 hrs? Because (duration like '1 hr%') will works in case of <2hrs only. Ryt?

Comment: Oh i know that, but is there any way to make the query flexible to execute with different durations?

Comment: @noob finally i could do it.thanx 4 pointing out the obvious mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (without using REGEX):

```
select * from TableName
where (duration not like '%hr%')
      OR (duration like '1 hr%')
```

Result:

```
JOBNO   DURATION
1       1 hr
3       1 hr 30 mins
5       1 hr 15 min
6       45 mins
7       30 min
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ffb7/13).

**Explanation:**

The first condition in `WHERE` clause will fetch the records with duration doesn't contain the word 'hr' (which will be the minutes only). Second condition is to fetch duration starting with `1 hr`, which will be the duration between 1hr-2hr.

**EDIT:**

To make it more flexible, you can do this:

```
select * from TableName
where (duration not like '%hr%')
      OR (CAST(SUBSTRING(duration,1,2) AS UNSIGNED) < 4)
```

Result:

```
JOBNO   DURATION
1       1 hr
2       3 hrs
3       1 hr 30 mins
4       2 hrs 15 mins
5       1 hr 15 min
6       45 mins
7       30 min
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ffb7/29).

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to solve the problem in SQL, the language is not rich enough.  Instead, use Perl or PHP or some language that has a good REGEXP library.

1. Add a new column.
2. Fetch the rows, convert them in your application language, then UPDATE the new column.
3. Drop the existing column -- or keep it for human readability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably. It will be painful and is really over-engineering a solution here.

The general purpose of a database is to speed up access and, in general, regular expressions are expensive. Another problem here is that there might not be a promise about how these time strings are stored. In the example that you give, you need to parse out the number value to decide if "hr" or "hrs" should be expected next.

I would suggest instead storing the durations in seconds (as a MySQL `INT`). You can then quickly and easily search and sort on that `INT`:

```
jobno | duration
-------------------
1     |  3600
2     |  10800
3     |  5400
4     |  8100
5     |  4500
6     |  2700
7     |  1800
```

The "less than two hours" query would then look like this:

```
SELECT `jobno` FROM `jobs` WHERE `duration` < 7200;
```